# How to access this function in controller directives unit testing using jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

How to access delegateDirective in unit test?

```
angular.module('sampleApp').directive('sampleDirective', function ($rootScope) {


  return {

    transclude: true,
    scope: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/index.html',
    restrict: 'EA',
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

      ........
      this.deleteDirective = function (message, clickAction) {
       .......
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access deleteDirective method directly even using directive scope.We write these kind of methods,if we want to have a child directive for 'sampleDirective'.There you can use it by injecting controller into link function of child.